# Generating the mandelbrot set - zoom, area and iteration depth

Tags: python, mandelbrot

I have a list of areas of interest where I would like to zoom into the Mandelbrot set. Unfortunately, I don't know the iteration depths to be used.

**Question 1:** Given (x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max), is there a formula providing a rule of thumb for a reasonable max iteration depth?

**Question 2**: Given a nice picture, is there a formula providing a rule of thumb how to adjust the max iteration depth when zooming into this picture? like `new_max_iter = func(zoom, new_zoom, max_iter)`

I am using the iteration number to colorize the set:

```
def calc_mandel(x_space, y_space, max_iter=50):
    res_arr = []
    for y in y_space:
        row = []
        for x in x_space:
            c = complex(x,y)
            z = 0
            for i in range(max_iter):
                if (z * z.conjugate()).real > 4.0:
                    row.append(i)
                    break
                else: 
                    z = z**2 + c
            else:
                row.append(0)
        res_arr.append(row)
    return res_arr
```

and

```
graph = ax.pcolormesh(x_space, y_space, res_arr, cmap='magma')
```

Comment: You need to tag what language that is.

Comment: Only w.r.t. performance b/c it omits the square root.

Comment: The one I am using b/c it is essentially (x^2 + y2) > 4.0 instead of sqrt(x^2 + y^2) > 2.0. But that does not affect the result, and it has nothing to do with my question ;-)

Comment: Strange. Seems to depend on the way abs() is implemented. I did a profiling years ago and my way was faster. Now they are pretty much on a par, 62.8 sec for my way vs. 58.9 for abs(). Profiling via cProfile for three different zooms into the mandelbrot set. The profiling showed that there's more optimization potential in the nested loop which consumes about 50% of the time.  Anyway - back to topic.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/16970 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/31871652

Comment: I compare with 2.0 (or 4.0).

Comment: I added another question which is simply, given a working max_iter for some zoom factor, how to *adjust max_iter* when zooming into the set with higher resolution.

Comment: One way I have used, is so make a tally of the average iteration (absolute) depth difference between neighbours. The flat areas have a difference of 0 or 1, It's the apparently chaotic region close to the MSet that is of interest, and if there isn't enough variation between neighbours, the iteration depth needs increasing. It's also useful to keep track of the minimum iterations found.